# How to get a photo path in PHP Laravel web service

Tags: php, laravel, image, phpmyadmin, store

I want to make a web service using PHP Laravel which can store images.
I have made a table testing containing a colum named `Photo`. Now I need to make a controller to save the photo file.

Testing Table:

```
Description (string) null
Photo (binary) null
```

In the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
    $photo = $request->input('photo');

    $data = new Testing();
    $data->Photo = $photo;

    if ( $data->save() ) {
        $res['message'] = 'Success';
        $res['value'] = $data;

        return response ( $res );
    } else {
        $res['message'] = 'Failed';

        return response ( $res );
    }
}
```

But when I hit it using postman, I choose binary for the body and I choose a .jpg file, it throws me an error saying that my photo file is null.

Can you tell me how to get the photo path in the right way?

Comment: Store file in storage directory and return full path when sending request from postman

Comment: is it required to store the image itself in the database (Binary)? or you will accept storing the image in Laravel storage directory and store the image path (Varchar) in the database?

Comment: @OmerAbdelmajeed i think it's the 2nd choice where i should store the path.. but when i use postman, and go to the binary tab for the body

how can i get the path? when i choose a file, it just shows me name.jpg but when i hit send, it gives me null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code to save photo

```
            if($request->hasFile('photo')){
                $image = $request->file('photo');
                $destination_path = public_path('/images/');
                $source = "Image".time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $image->move($destination_path, $source);
            }
            else{
                $source = 'default.jpg';
            }
            $add_new_photo = new Photo();
            $add_new_photo->photo = $source;
            $add_new_video->created_by = \Auth::user()->name;
            $add_new_video->save();
```

This will save the photo in the images folder. Make sure you create the folder using 777 mode.

Comment: i'll give it a try.. and will ask if i get another mistake ;D thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')){
  $image = $request->photo->store('your_image_folder');
  $data->Photo = basename($image);
  ...
}
```

The store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. If you want to name your file use

```
$request->photo->storeAs('your_image_folder', 'your_filename')
```

Then save *$data*

Comment: thanks for the response, but how can i get the folder path? or where do people usually put it? sorry newbie

Comment: You can store images in the public directory. Use the method **asset**  to get the folder path : [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of choosing binary in body.
You need to choose form-data in body.
and need to change the type of the field to form

Comment: i tried this one, but when i choose an image, it said that the field is null